# Apache .htaccess Remove Trailing Slashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Ok, I have googled enough, found enough blogs and enough SO threads on this very topic, but NONE of those solutions worked for me.

I have created folders, so they're accessible via URLs like these:

- http://mysite.com/folder1/
- http://mysite.com/folder2/

ALL I want to do is, make them accessible via these:

- http://mysite.com/folder1
- http://mysite.com/folder2

So basically, remove the trailing slash.

Comment: You definitely did not searched for it...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have **turned off** a [DirectorySlash Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) in you Apache configuration.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ http%3://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(?:^|;\s*)redirect=301
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ http%3://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,CO=redirect:301:%1:0:/]
```

Comment: @user1437328 - If you are sure your directory slash is turned off in your Apache configuration, then most likely your browser is automatically adding a trailing slash (which should not!). I have updated my answer with "loop prevention mechanism" using cookies, so redirection should not jump into loop...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following rewrite to removed trailing slashes.

```
# remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

You will need mod_rewrite enabled. This can be put in an .htaccess file or the apache configuration.

Comment: Nope, no luck! btw, my .htaccess is in /home/user/www/mysite.com/.htaccess while folder1 is /home/user/www/mysite.com/folder1 (same with folder2

Comment: Using redirection flag `[R]` you have to provide full url (http...)

Comment: Can you confirm if mod_rewrite is enabled on the server? Can you run PHP on the server? If so you can follow these instructions http://serverfault.com/questions/397168/how-to-i-test-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled